# Why can't I parse "0-2-6-1​" to ints after splitting by '-'

Tags: c#

Reading from an Excel Worksheet that was copy and pasted with a list of string speperated numbers, why will c# not convert a char/string 0 to a zero or a char/string 1 to an int 1 after splitting the string into an array by '-'?

It seems like there is a character problem, the difference between a 1 and a 1 with no line at the bottom?

Thanks

Comment: Please share the code and specific undesired & ideal behavior so that we can help troubleshoot.

Comment: " a 1 and a 1 with no line at the bottom" - sounds like an 'l' crept in (as i 'hello')

Comment: [Here is a hopefully working .NET Fiddle example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9cKNk6).

Comment: `'0'` has ASCII code `0x30` or `48`.  Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts...  I did a work around that successfully replaced the "1" that I copied and pasted from the sheet but no luck with "0" so I used a conditional statement once I was sure the rest of the numbers were converting...

string numCell = ws.Cells[r, 2].Value.ToString().Replace("1​","1").Replace("0", "0").Trim();
draw.Draw = numCell;

//couldn't convert int.Parse when "0" so had to use tryParse and failure =="0" in conditional statement

draw.Numbers = Array.ConvertAll(numCell.Split('-'), n => int.TryParse(n, out i) ? i : 0);

Answer (score 2):

The result of spliting  a  string is an array of string, which in case they are numeric you should further parse into integer.

```
var str = "0-2-6-1";
var stringValues = str.Split('-'); //  string[] values

var intValues = Array.ConvertAll(stringValues, s => int.Parse(s)); // int[] values
```

Comment: No lambda needed, `int.Parse` is perfectly usable as the second parameter by itself.

Comment: This is the code I was using, however it often fails to convert a "1" or a "0" with either int.Parse or int.TryParse...strange.  "0-2-6-1​" is directly copy and pasted from the sheet so I know it is not an 'O' or an 'l' ...thanks